# Delete an array containing Objects MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working in a project oj NodeJS, and I want to delete an element of array containing objets.

The Schema is:

```js
{
  "products" : [
    {
      "productid" : 1,
      "name" : "product 1",
      "price" : 200
      
    },
    {
      "productid" : 2,
      "name" : "product 2",
      "price" : 300
      
    },
    {
      "productid" : 3,
      "name" : "product 3",
      "price" : 350
      
    },
    {
      "productid" : 4,
      "name" : "product 4",
      "price" : 300
      
    },
,
    {
      "productid" : 5,
      "name" : "product 5",
      "price" : 300
      
    }
    
  ]
}
```

And i want to delete product 3, how is query in mongodb? the "productid" attribute is key, does not repeat it

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

Change `collection` name and `{}` as per your need.

```
db.collection.update( {}, { "$pull" : { "products" : { "productid" : 3 } } });
```

if it matches multiple element then use multi option like

```
db.collection.update( {}, { "$pull" : { "products" : { "productid" : 3 } } }, 
{ multi: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update( {<query>}, { "$pull" : { "products.productid" : 3  } });
```